# Using <kbd> tag obscures text on the following line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, formatting

When using the `<kbd>` tag in posts, the text in the "buttons" is large enough that it obscures some of the text in the following line, making it a bit difficult to see. [Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/adding-a-new-line-on-facebook-comment/9737#9737):

> To add a newline, simply type
>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>   This will insert a newline character
>   (thus making a new line) rather than
>   enter, which causes the form to
>   submit.

The buttons don't *overlap* with the next line, but are touching it, and make it somewhat difficult to read and a bit bizarre looking. Perhaps this is by design, but I think it would look better if the buttons were a tad smaller, so as to not touch the next line of text.

Error occurs on Windows 7 in Google Chrome 7.0.517.44 and in Firefox 4 Beta 5, and possibly other browsers (those are the only two I tested). It seems worse in Firefox than in Chrome.

Comment: I'll decrease the KBD text size a bit and adjust the padding accordingly, so the "button" will be smaller.

Comment: @Jin, thanks. Once the change has been made, if you post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: will do!

Comment: FWIW, it looks fine to me. I hadn't noticed any issues with the KBD tag prior to this. (Firefox 3.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the change for this. It will be in the next deployment. I made the KBD text slightly smaller and decreased the padding a bit. While it's still fairly close to the next line, I believe you'll find it easier to read than before.